# Not able to login in cakephp 3.0.8

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

When I try to login it says "Invalid email or password, try again". I have used default password hasher and without it also but I am getting the same result with the both. And also default validation is also not working. 
code for login.

```
public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            //pr($user);die;
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                if ($this->Auth->authenticationProvider()->needsPasswordRehash()) {
                  $user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
                  $user->password = $this->request->data('password');
                  $this->Users->save($user);
                }
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            else { 
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'),'default',[],'auth');
                 }
        }
    }
```

code for validation.

```
// src/Model/Table/UsersTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator
            ->notEmpty('email', 'A email is required')
            ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required')
           ;
    }

}
```

If anybody needs some more info please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done the basic checks that are suggested in the other questions about login problems that can be found here on SO? Column length, password really stored hashed, etc... also, "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, please be more specific as to what the problem with the validation is!

Comment: Thanks ndm for the reply.
password is really stored in a hashed format and in DB its datatype is varchar with length 255. I have mention in the problem description that ' When I try to login it says "Invalid email or password, try again". I have used default password hasher and without it also but I am getting the same result with the both.' Problem with validation is that if I leave the columns blank it doesn't give any message.

Comment: Tip. If someone (especially with some rep) asks for info that you think is in the question: _it is almost certainly not in the question_, repeating the question in a comment is not helpful. Check the sql log for whether there is a query which would find the right user, check [the source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Auth/DefaultPasswordHasher.php#L68) to see if the submitted password _actually_ matches the hash stored in the db.

Comment: Thanks @AD7six for the reply.
I will check the log whether it is finding the right user or not. But like I said that if I am not using hashing (normal way) for password it is again saying "Invalid email or password, try again". I have checked the Mysql and if not using hashing, password is stored in a normal way.

Comment: So you've checked the SQL log, and what does it say? What does the query look like, and does it find anything? In case something is found, check whether the retrieved password hash is valid (**http://php.net/password_get_info**), either by reading the user manually, or as @AD7six suggested in the core code. And your validation, where do you apply it? What exactly does the data look like? Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: `if I am not using hashing (normal way)` - that is not normal. `I have checked the Mysql and if not using hashing, password is stored in a normal way` - if you mean in plain text that is not normal, recommended or a good idea. Until you add to the question some information which indicates what's happening - you're not likely to get an answer.